# Moving a MSSQL and IIS server to AWS - Web Applications that use Integrated Authentication

Tags: sql-server, iis, amazon-web-services, asp.net

I have been tasked with migrating a solution that contains a few WCF services and a ASP.Net v4.0 website from individual MSSQL and IIS servers to the Amazon Web Services infrastructure.

Whilst I have no concerns with finding the right product on AWS to do this, I have concerns with the applications themselves. The web application authenticates users via Integrated Authentication and the web services take the username passed from the ASP.Net application and evaluate the user's access to data by Active Directory groups.

This will break when everything is moved to AWS correct? I believe that it will fail in 2 parts: 1) No integrated auth will take place 2) web services will be unable to contact the Active Directory server.

I was wondering if anyone had any experiences with a similar issue, I can revisit the projects at a code level exposing LADP for authentication to the web services and redevelop authentication in the ASP .Net site to take a manual login and auth over LADP but this is pretty invasive and project timelines aren't that accommodating.

Ideas thoughts and whatever are highly welcomed :)

Xavier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as AWS instances have network access to your AD servers and are properly joined to the domain, no problems occur when trying to do integrated authentication in AWS.

When your companies security policies do not allow external access to your ADC, you might want to look into AWS' private cloud offerings, which configure a private VPN channel between your datacenter and amazon's. That way the AWS instances can become "internal" machines in your network without exposing your ADC to the wider internet.

If neither of those options works for you, you are correct in inferring that you were given an impossible task.

Comment: Thank you David for your help, I believe that the best and possibly only solution is to investigate the Private Cloud offering of AWS.